# What to do when trying to create an Android app, and 'No Target Available'?

Tags: android, eclipse

I'm trying to create an Android project with Eclipse, but the 'Next' button is greyed out in the New Android Project window.

The Build Target section is presenting the message 'No Target Avaliable'. I have everything else filled in. Is there something else I need to have in place for this to work?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Did you make sure to point the SDK Manager of android to the directory where you installed the SDK?**

Without this path, then it won't allow you to select any android version you do this by going to:

windows -> preferences -> android

then set the path to your SDK then hit apply. And it should populate with versions available.

Hope this helps.

Update: Also be sure to make an emulator if you plan to use an emulator by going to:

Window -> Android SDK and AVD Manager and make an emulator with like 10 mibs of space and you should be golden.

Answer (score 1):

Have you set the location of the SDK in Windows > Preferences > Android?

Answer (score 0):

Have you created any AVDs? In my Eclipse, for the New Android Project dialog, the Build Target groupbox lists the AVDs that I've created as targets with checkboxes beside their names.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. If [JoxTraex' suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5023944/what-to-do-when-trying-to-create-an-android-app-and-no-target-available/5023976#5023976) above doesn't seem to do anything, try quitting and restarting Eclipse, and setting the preference again. That's what made it work for me.

Answer (score 0):

My equal problem was a duplicate install in two different folders.

check if the path in  environment settings is the same as the one the android studio link uses. In my case the paths were :

```
C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\bin
```

and

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk.
```

The last was the right one. Discovered by running the command 'android' which opened

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\sdk manager.exe
```

not

```
C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\bin\studio64.exe
```

Installed API versions were declared 'uninstalled'.

I advise you to uninstall all Android API versions in that last one too.