# Target dropdown not available when creating AVD

Tags: android-emulator

In the SDK Manager when attempting to create a new Android Device ( AVD ), the target dropdown box is greyed out and non functional.
This is my first time setting this up. Any idea what I missed?

Comment: duplicate:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5023944/what-to-do-when-trying-to-create-an-android-app-and-no-target-available

Answer (score 2):

Same thing happened to me while trying during the installer. After the SDK finishes downloading, make sure to restart ADB (which it prompts to do) and the target box will become selectable.